# Find the limit $\quad\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^3}{\tan^3(2x)}$

Tags: limits, derivatives

I'm trying to find the limit $$\quad\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^3}{\tan^3(2x)}$$ but I'm at a loss.

I've tried expanding $\tan^3(2x)$ using $\tan2x = \frac{\sin2x}{\cos2x}$, and then using double-angle formulas to expand that, but that did not yield anything helpful from what I could tell.

---

This is a question from an end-of-chapter exercise. Up and til this chapter this book has only dealt with introductory-type limits and consequently introduced the derivative and differentiation rules. That being said, I'm not supposed to apply some *fancy* technique that I've not been introduced to thus far.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Remember that $\sin(x)/x \to 1$ as $x \to 0$. Thus so does $\tan(x)/x \to 1$ as $x\to 0$. Also note that $\sin(2x)/x = 2(\sin(2x)/(2x)) \to 2 \cdot 1 = 2$.

Comment: Also $\sin^3(x)/x^3 = ( \sin(x)/x )^3 \to 1^3$ as $x \to 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^3}{\sin^3(2x)}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{8}\cdot\frac{(2x)^3}{\sin^3(2x)}=\frac{1}{8}\cdot1$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** 
$$
\tan'(x) = 1+\tan^2x \in [1,1+\epsilon]
$$for $|x|\le \delta_\epsilon$ and $\delta_\epsilon$ little enough.

Integrate this inequality, it proves that
$$
|y|<\delta_\epsilon \implies y \le \tan (y)\le (1+\epsilon) y
$$